# Display a user's picture or avatar in the header using twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to insert the user's avatar next to the username in the bootstrap 3 header. I'm having a very hard time achieving this, and I don't want to hack into the provider's css. Any one has already done this ? Thanks for your help

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Foo's Bar</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Awesome link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">More Awesome link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/Chuck">Something <span id ="toto" class="badge" style="@danger">0</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/30x30"><span class="header-username">Chuck Norris</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Edit : the Bootply's link, because that's what friends do ! http://www.bootply.com/X4FhzJiP3T

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The avatar is appearing to the left of the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The avatar appears next to the username. If it's a styling or placement issue you're experiencing, just add a custom class to the avatar image and style accordingly

```
.avatar {
    /* put custom avatar css here */
}
```

I also added the `.img-responsive` class to the avatar...

```
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" class="avatar img-responsive">
        <span class="header-username">Chuck Norris</span>
    </a>
</li>
```